# R, adding an attribute to each row of a Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, attributes, higher-order-functions

In R, I have a matrix: `matClust4` which holds all vectors that are in cluster 4 after executing the `kmeans` algorithm.

`matClust4` has dimensions 27 X 31 and has the `rownames` attribute set for each vector.
What I would like to do is give another attribute to each row vector in `matClust4`

I would prefer to use the `apply` function. I would like to try something like this:

```
apply(matClust4, 1, function(v) SOME_ATTRIBUTE(v) = idClust4)

#where idClust4 is some previous calculated result
```

1. How can I create/use an attribute of `matClust4` to do this?

Comment: I don't think you can do this.  The rows are not individual objects, so they can't have separate attributes.  If you can fit the attributes into a vector, you can use `attr(matClust4,"WHATEVER") <- vector_of_whatever` (similarly, the `rownames` attribute is a single vector associated with `matClust4`, not a set of individual attributes associated with rows)

Comment: Perhaps if you explained your reasons for wanting an extra attribute, it would be possible to provide alternative means to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You woud not need to use `apply` for that purpose if the to-be-assigned values had already been computed (and had the same number of elements as `matClust4` had rows. You should just assign an R attribute with:

```
 attr(matClust4, 'SOME_ATTRIBUTE') = idClust4
```

This is how Frank Harrell creates value labels for datasets he imports from SAS. You do need to be careful that reordering or alterations of the dataframe could upset the association with the vector, since there would be enforcement of consistency by `[<-` or `sort` or `order`.

Comment: This gives me an attribute for matClust4, but like `rownames` I would like an attribute for every row.

Comment: The 'rownames` attribute is just a vector with as many elements as the dataframe (or matrix)  has rows. You would get the n-th rowname with `rownames(matClust4)[n]`. If you what you really want is a new column, you need to stop calling this new thing an 'attribute'. If you just want a new columns then do this: `matClust4$newcol <- idClust4`

Comment: I just did `attr(matClust4, "clustID") <- ids` where `ids` is a vector with the same amount of rows as `matClust4`. Now, R will not let me access `clustID` though with `matClust4$clustID`. How do I fix this?

Comment: As I said. If you want another column you should use a different form. You do not access R attributes wit the $ function. And I should have added that if you are working with the `$` funciton that you are also _not_ working with a 'matrix'. That function only works with lists and dataframes.

Comment: Well since I have a matrix, what is the best way to associate some attribute/datamember with each row vector in the matrix? I don't really know too much about R, so I probably used the wrong language when talking about attributes. But, what I would like to do is to access this attribute/datamember of each row vector by something like: `matClust4.clustID[27]` -- get this attribute/datamember of row vector 27 in `matClust4`

Comment: Thanks for the help. You have made it clear to me that what I am thinking in terms of attributes in R is not correct. So, now I am asking a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022680/r-datamembers-and-attributes

Comment: I should correct myself. the "$" function also works for environments.