# R datamembers and Attributes

Tags: r, oop, class, attributes, datamember

I am very new to R and am not sure about the proper language when referring to datamembers and attributes of an object. I have an object-oriented programming language background in Java so I am probably referring to datamembers/attributes in a Java set of mind. Anyway, suppose I have a matrix `matClust1` and I have done the following:

```
ids = vector()
for(i in 1:size)              #size is the number of rows in matClust1
{
  ids = c(ids, "exp")
}

attr(matClust1, "clustID") <- ids
```

I think of the above as setting an attribute/datamember of each row vector in `matClust1` to `"exp"`. This is because `ids` is created to have as many entries as there are rows in `matClust1`. So, I would like to be able to access this attribute/datamember by code like the following:

```
matClust1.clustID[2]            #get the clustID of row vector in matClust1
```

Apparently the `.` operator does not do this nor does the `$` operator.

1. How can I achieve this functionality in R?

**EDIT:** I already have the attribute set for `rownames` and what I am really looking for is another variable to work like `rownames`.

Comment: In addition to a specific solution, which will probably involve using `rownames()`, you should _definitely_ read the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), particularly Circles 2+3, if you're coming from a Java background. It will save you a lot of pain.

Comment: just a quick tip - `.` is not an operator in `R`.  It is just another character. When you see `.` think `_` (underscore)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta: That is only partially true. The truth is restricted to data-object naming. The naming of functions using the S3 dispatch system does rely on "." having special significance. But for the OP, that is a method for function dispatch which is _not_ going to translate well into Java-trained thought processes.

Comment: Based on your edit, I would recommend either switching to a data frame or using a more full fledged object type structure, like S4 or Reference classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a `data.frame` or `data.table` instead.

E.g.

```
df = data.frame(matClust1)

# create a new column and assign whatever to it:
df$clustID = "exp"

# use it however you like
df$someOtherColumn = paste(1:dim(df)[1], df$clustID)
```